# when the page scroll to certain point, how to make a second fixed header appear

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that will be responsive and I also want to add a header that appears once the visitor scrolls for a bit. The header will supplant the main header in order to be visible as the user travels down the page.

I think this was a convention that people have used, and I need some help, as i can't really code it from scratch.

Has anyone seen examples or tutorials on this. I've looked but can't come up with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Twitter Bootstrap framework's Navigation header http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

> **Static top navbar** Create a full-width navbar that scrolls away with
>   the page by adding .navbar-static-top. Unlike the .navbar-fixed-top
>   class, you do not need to change any padding on the body.